# Automate a process using bash script

Tags: linux, shell-script, process

I have a unimrcp client process (ucp) and I want to spawn multiple ucp using shell script.

Whenever I spawn a ucp, it returns a command line using which I can access different functionalities in ucp. So I want to write a script that achieves following,

1. Spawn a ucp process
2. wait until the ucp's command line appears
3. access ucp's functionality with a command "run recog"

Note that ./ucp && run recog does not work since ./ucp is finished only after we exit from the command line of ucp.

I tried the following for this,

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
./ucp &                                                               
fg                                                                              
echo "run recog uni2"                                                           
wait
```

However, `./ucp &` results into starting the client process and then writing "?????" on the client console resulting into "????" command not found. Following are the logs,

```
./script.sh

2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Set Property ip:127.0.0.1
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMU]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMA]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [L16]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechsynth]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechrecog]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [recorder]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speakverify]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620593 [INFO]   Register Resource Factory
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create SofiaSIP Agent [SIP-Agent-1] [1.12.11-227-g73efc97] sip:127.0.0.1:8062;transport=udp
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [SIP-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create RTSP Client [RTSP-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [RTSP-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create MRCPv2 Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Connection Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create Media Engine [Media-Engine-1]
unknown command: ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Is this the right way to achieve what I mentioned in the question? (spawn a client and run a command on its console)? If yes, why does the "./ucp &" results in reading "?????" considering that as input to its console? Note that this does not happen if I simply fire "./ucp & fg " from the console. It can see the expected behavior of the command when I do it from the console. The issue appears when I try to execute the script.

If this is not a right way, How can I achieve what I mentioned in the question? (1, 2, and 3)

Update--
`./ucp &` returns the control to a process (background process I think), which consideres whatever outputs printed on the terminal as inputs to the console of ./ucp. I think I need to somehow transfer the IO control to ./ucp process or not? Not sure..

Thank you

Comment: Something along the lines of `echo "run recog uni2" | ./ucp &` possible instead ?

Comment: Thank you Steve. That results into the same issue I mentioned. Specifically, ./ucp & is spawning the client and outputs some of the logs. Whatever logs that it outputs, a process (not sure which one but most probably background process) considers all those logs as the commands that should be entered on the console. I think I need to tell the background process to return the IO control to ./ucp &. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complicated way is to use `expect` which fakes a full terminal for the process to play around in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
# Spawn a ucp process
spawn -noecho ucp
# wait until the ucp's command line appears
expect -ex "whatever the ucp command line prompt looks like here"
# access ucp's functionality with a command "run recog"
send -- "run recog\r"
# not sure what needs to happen here, so let's wait for
# ucp to exit (may also need to handle timeout or 
# the output buffer being full or ...)
expect eof
```

Then you could run the above script as `runucp &` or whatever you decide to call it in your shell.

As a side note, the simpler `echo blah | ...` standard input method will sometimes fail as programs can discard input, for example a program could discard all input prior to presenting the first prompt via either reading and throwing away that input:

```
% cat prompter
#!/usr/bin/env expect
sleep 3         ;# simulate load of something big and bloated
read stdin      ;# toss any existing input
puts -nonewline "prompt> "
puts "got >>>[gets stdin]<<<"
% print -l a b c d e f g | ./prompter
prompt> got >>><<<
```

or via a `tcflush(3)` call. `expect` allows one to avoid this condition via the `expect -x "detect prompt here"` call that indicates that the spawned process is likely up and ready for input.

Comment: You're awesome! That works!! I am a beginner in shell script. I looked into expect but didn't think of the solution in this way. It's pretty cool. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does `ucp` accept input on stdin? If yes, try piping your command:

```
echo "run recog" | ./ucp
```

Comment: Thank you Rudi. It results into the same issue I mentioned above. I think ./ucp is spawning the client and whatever happens on the terminal after that (logs and all things printed on terminal) are considered as a new command to be executed. I think I need to somehow control the IO and hand it over to a different process. what do you think?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if output to the screen could be used as an input anywhere else (unless measures are taken like piping or `tee`ing).

Comment: Yea. I think of the same. that's why I am not sure what's happing. Thank you very much for looking into it though. I really appreciate this. @thring's solution works.